# Why when I use the search method below it only works for the first three contacts in my list?

Tags: c#

All the relevant code is below and works fine, what I cannot figure out is why my search method is only working with the first three contacts in the list. "Marie" "Cassidy" and any contact below that cannot be found.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
namespace SmsApp.Models
{
    public class Contacts
    {
        public List<Friend> contacts = new List<Friend>()
        {    
            new Friend("Alan", "Peck", "087", "4138776"),
            new Friend("Bill", "Murray", "085", "6542777"),
            new Friend("Jim", "Beglin", "086", "7865392"),
            new Friend("Marie", "Cassidy", "085", "1111111"),
            new Friend("Shane", "Flynn", "089", "2345634"),
            new Friend("Tom", "Murray", "087", "9876543"),
            new Friend("Jeff", "Banks", "087", "6372876"),
            new Friend("Richie", "Towell", "085", "0098765"),
            new Friend("Niall", "Doyle", "087", "0009876"),
            new Friend("Sarah", "Lambe", "085", "2238765")
        };

        //This method searches through the 'contacts' List for a match
        public String search(string destAreaCode, string destNumber)
        {
            //looks for input parameter matching item within the List of Person objects 
            int destAreaIndex = contacts.FindIndex(x => x.destArea == destAreaCode);
            //looks for input parameter matching item within the List of Person objects 
            int destNumIndex = contacts.FindIndex(x => x.destNum == destNumber);

            if (destAreaIndex == destNumIndex)
                //this return value string is passed to the 'Success' View, which displays it to the user 
                return "Your message was sent to " + contacts.ElementAt(destAreaIndex).foreName + " " + contacts.ElementAt(destAreaIndex).surName;
            //this return value is used within an if statement to redirect user to the 'Error' View / User does not see the content of this string
            else return "nomatch";    
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the method?

Comment: Since `contacts` is a `List<Friend>` you don't have to use `ElementAt`.  You can just do `contacts[destAreaIndex]` instead.

Comment: Or even better, you use `.Find` to pull the actual object.

Comment: Hi john, code that calls the method is below..

Comment: if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // instantiate a new Contacts object to search the List within
               Contacts testContacts = new Contacts();
                // and assign output to a  new string 
                  string search = testContacts.search(sms.destAreaCode, sms.destNumber);
                
                TempData["searchoutput"] = search;

     TempData["message"] = sms.smsText;

                
                if (search == "nomatch")
                    return RedirectToAction("Error");

Comment: @Duncarn You should add that to the question, not put it into a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try finding Mary Cassidy, whose area code is `"085"` and number is `"1111111"`.

- You search your list for the first occurrence of `"085"`. You find Bill Murray's index.
- You search your list for the first occurrence of `"1111111"`. You find Mary Cassidy's index.
- You check if the two indices are equal. They aren't. No match.

You should instead find the first occurrence that matches both conditions at the same time.

```
var contact = contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.destArea == destAreaCode 
                                        && x.destNum == destNumber);
```

We use `FirstOrDefault` because there may be no match, and we don't want to throw an exception when there is no match. Now we just check for null to decide whether there was a match.

```
if (contact != null)
    return "Your message was sent to " + contact.foreName + " " + contact.surName;
return "nomatch";
```

Answer (score 5):

This happens because you have duplicate area code entries. Let's say you're searching for a friend with area code "085". `FindIndex` will always return the first item it finds.

Your search function should look like this:

```
public String search(string destAreaCode, string destNumber)
{
    var friend = contacts.FistOrDefault(x=>x.destArea == destAreaCode && x.destNum ==destAreaCode);
    if (friend != null)
    {
        //do some stuff
    } else 
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple items in the list with the same area code. So when you search for a specific area code, it will return the first item that matches that area code, although what you want might be to find the item further down in the list.

The solution to this is to use `FindIndex` only once for the two conditions combined like this:

```
int index = contacts.FindIndex(x => x.destArea == destAreaCode && x => x.destNum == destNumber);
```

Please note that in this case, you would need to check if index is equal -1 to detect if there are no matches.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a search for this record:

```
new Friend("Marie", "Cassidy", "085", "1111111")
```

You would call the method as such:

```
search("085", "1111111")
```

Within that method, your first call to `FindIndex()` is going to return `1`, because that's the first matching record.  Your second call to `FindIndex()` is going to return `3`, because that's the first matching record.

This then evaluates to `false`:

```
if (destAreaIndex == destNumIndex)
```

So no match is found.

---

Instead of finding two separate records, why not just find the *one* record you're looking for?:

```
var match = contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.destArea == destAreaCode && c.destNum == destNumber);
```

If `match` is `null`, no record was found.  If it has a value, that's the matching record and can be used:

```
return "Your message was sent to " + match.foreName + " " + match.surName;
```

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there is more than one match.  `FirstOrDefault` would probably be a better option depending on what the OP wants to happen when there are multiple matches.

Comment: @juharr: Or, `FirstOrDefault` could be hiding the presence of bad data.  It's a matter of personal preference.  I'm generally in the "fail early and often" camp, implementing *only* the functionality needed/desired and letting the system tell me if something goes wrong.  How the OP wants to handle duplicate data (which doesn't currently exist) is another concern entirely.

Comment: I just wanted to point out the potential exception to the OP and let them decide what to do.